# Converting JSON Array to Java Array always throws empty values

Tags: java, gson

So I have this variable specCifDetailsReturn which contains the ff. payload

```
[
{"ax21:cHType":"S",
"ax21:cardNumber":4***********7126,"ax21:returnCde":"00",
"ax21:cancelCode":"",
"ax21:vipCode":"",
"ax21:custrNbr":"0*****3426"},

{"ax21:cHType":"S",
"ax21:cardNumber":4***********3038,"ax21:returnCde":"00",
"ax21:cancelCode":"H",
"ax21:vipCode":"",
"ax21:custrNbr":"0*****3426"}
]
```

And the ff. Model Class to extract the params I need from the Array

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)
public final class SpecCifInfo {

    @JsonAlias("ax21:cHType")
    private String cHType;

    @JsonAlias("ax21:cardNumber")
    private String cardNumber;

}
```

I am trying to convert it to a Java ArrayList so that I could loop into it and find a card number. But for some reason it always throws a null value on the log even though the specCifDetailsReturn variable has a value. Below is the snippet of my code.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<List<SpecCifInfo>>(){}.getType();
ArrayList<SpecCifInfo> specDetails = gson.fromJson(specCifDetailsReturn.toString(),type);

for (SpecCifInfo specInfo : specDetails){
     LOGGER.debug("Spec CIF Details", specInfo.getCHType() + "-" + specInfo.getCardNumber());
            }
```

Sample Output of the SpecCifInfo Object that has null values
[image]

Comment: Hi Joshua, it might be a little problem on somewhere. I tried your code snippet and sample data and it works fine. Maybe you can check 'Gson' version, I used 2.8.8.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the empty SpecCifInfo objct,still empty in the logs even if i changed to 2.8.8 :/

Comment: My first thought is: those card numbers cannot be valid json. Those must be quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those annotations are for the Jackson library, and you are manually using Gson. You should either keep them and just let Spring handle the deserialization for you by specifying a `List<SpecCifInfo>` parameter in the controller method, or you should use GSON's `@SerializedName` annotation. Either way will work.

Comment: Of the two options I suggest ditching Gson, as the G seems to stand for `garbage` instead of `Google`.

Comment: Okay noted , I thought it would be possible with this two. I resorted to removing Gson and allow spring to deserialize and added additional model classes to specify the params to get on the payload. thx. Athis is my high level code.

 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                SpecCifInfo specCifInfo = objectMapper.readValue(specCifDetails,SpecCifInfo.class);

with SpecCifInfo having sub classes to desribe the payload for each param level.